# Am I a contrarian? Or something else?

Tags: single-word-requests

As I truly consider and muse about aspects of sincerity and truth in reality, I am beginning to think **so** differently to most, that it is frightening.

I feel as if others are regularly making vehement, extremely hubristic, non-detailed. error filled judgments all the time.

I know there are questions regarding contrarians.  From my description here, would I be considered one, or is there another word to describe me?

*Note: either an adjective or a noun would suit: "I am [a] _______"*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would say *thoughtful* not necessarily [*contrary*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/contrary) which is more of an emotional position, not intellectual – disagreeing to be deliberately obstructive.

Comment: Maybe, a *skeptic*, or *skeptical*.

Comment: *Contrarian* doesn't sum up what you actually are—just that you're opposite to *any* of those characteristics. Summing up all the opposites, I would say you're *conscientious*.

Comment: I think you need to more accurately describe your position here. For example, you say you find it ***frightening*** that you don't seem to think the same way as most people - with the implication that *what frightens you* is the perception that other people are insincere / untruthful. But are you truly frightened? Given the broad thrust of your text, it seems more likely to me that you actually ***look down on other people*** (because they don't adhere to your high moral standards). Where does "fear" come into it?

Answer (score 1):

You would only be a contrarian if you opposed (often merely for effect) everything that was suggested, and you did that without considering all possible merits.

I would say that you are currently **disenchanted**, that you may be a **sceptic/skeptic**, but might have become a **cynic** and are yet to reach the point of being **grill-pilled**.

**OED**

> **disenchanted** (adj.) Freed from enchantment or illusion.
>
> 1839   C. Dickens Nicholas Nickleby xxx. 297   *A crest-fallen, dispirited, disenchanted man.*

> **sceptic/skeptic** (adj. and n.)
>
> 2. One who doubts the validity of what claims to be knowledge in some particular department of inquiry (e.g. metaphysics, theology, natural science, etc.); popularly, one who maintains a doubting attitude with reference to some particular question or statement. Also, one who is habitually inclined rather to doubt than to believe any assertion or apparent fact that comes before him; a person of sceptical temper.

But You could say that you are becoming / were a cynic:

OED:

> **cynic**
>
> 2. A person disposed to rail or find fault; now usually: One who shows a disposition to disbelieve in the sincerity or goodness of human motives and actions, and is wont to express this by sneers and sarcasms; a sneering fault-finder.

MW:

> Full Definition of **cynic**
> *1: a faultfinding captious critic especially : one who believes that human conduct is motivated wholly by self-interest*

But those are rather negative, and you may choose to believe, as I do, that

> “Cynic, n. *A blackguard whose faulty vision sees things as they are, not as they ought to be.”*

from Ambrose Bierce, The Unabridged Devil's Dictionary is a better definition.

A more recent phrase I came across was the American English “**grill-pilled**.”  This seems to originate in the “blue pill – red pill” choice in the film, “The Matrix”.

The essence of “grill-pilled” is that the grill-pilled seem to have taken a medication that allows or causes them to pass the point of weariness with opinion-based commentary and concentrate on something more in tune with their own, and simpler, life, e.g. how to grill things.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=grill%20pilled

> **grill pilled**
>
> 1. to have experienced a blithe resignation to the failure of leftist/progressive movements to overcome neoliberalism, electoralism and fascist nationalism; couples with a semi-ironic desire to profess bourgeois attitudes of political apathy, jocular antagonism to politics, and idolize outward symbols of petty materialism, a.k.a. the grill
>
> *After his years-long attempts to proselytize progressive and socialist policies were crushed by big-donor establishment Democrats, Mattleby became grill pilled and happily ignored the election news cycle, instead choosing to post about new rib rub recipes while the globe burned.*

Once you are fully grill-pilled, the things of which you complain will no longer have any significance or interest.